# Mark all files as "Embedded Resource" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, embedded-resource

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

I need to mark my xml files as "Embedded Resource".

I can do this process by opening the properties tab and then select the "Build Action" property as "Embedded Resource". I guess it is the normal way.

But I have a folder that has large number of generated xml files (400 approx) And I want them all to be marked as "Embedded Resource". Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all your XML files within VS and change them all to Embedded Resource just as you would with a single file.

Select all the files and then go to the Properties tab just as you would a single file and change the Build Action to Embedded Resource; it will propagate to all the previously selected files.

Comment: Yes thats the answer. I thought I have tried that already. But then I realized that folder has some other files too. When I select only the xml files, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the information you're updating is stored in the .csproj file. Can you write something that parses the .csproj XML to update it automatically?